# listnode loop, segmentation fault

Tags: c++, linked-list

Haven't managed to find a simplified version of this problem.

I'm new to listnodes so I probably just don't understand something simplea bout them. Everything seems to work until I pass my for loop.

```
while(temp2 != NULL){

    for(int i = temp2->data; i > 0; i--){
    //////////////
    temp1 = head;
    temp3 = Product.head;

        while(temp1 != NULL || temp3 != NULL){
            cout << "\ntemp1->data: " << temp1->data;
            cout << "\ntemp3->data: " << temp3->data;


            temp1 = temp1->next;
            temp3 = temp3->next;
        }
    /////////////
    cout << "\n\ndecrement: " << i;
    }

temp2 = temp2->next;    
}
```

Everything runs except between the comments.

My thought was that I could traverse to the end of the listnode (temp1), then once I reached the end I point back to the head and traverse through it as many times as necessary. I'm getting a segmentation fault there though.

I cant traverse through temp2 just fine, what am I doing wrong though when it comes to traversing through temp1 multiple times? Can I only refer to the head of the list once?

edit: I figured out that I just left a conditional in. Now Its my 3rd list that is giving me the segmentation fault. it will run for a single loop but once out of the while loop it breaks.

Comment: The || condition should be an &&.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this. In a specific iteration of your while loop, `temp1` points to an address and `temp1->next` points to `NULL`. `temp3` points to an address and `temp3->next` also points to an address.

```
temp1 == address

temp1->next == NULL

temp3 == address

temp3->next == NULL
```

You iterate through the current address, printing the data from `temp1` and `temp3`. Then you set them equal to their next pointers. Now `temp1` points to `NULL` and `temp3` points to an address.

Your condition of the while loop checks to see if either of the pointers do not point to `NULL`. Because `temp3` does not point to `NULL`, it will try to print out the data for `temp1` and `temp3`. But this will cause a problem because `temp1` points to `NULL` and you are trying to dereference a `NULL` pointer, which will cause a segmentation fault.

To solve this issue, you should use an AND (&&) condition for your while loop so that it only prints when `temp1` AND `temp3` don't point to `NULL`.